# RedisTimeoutException is crashing my aspnet core application

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

When my application traffic gets high, `StackExchange.Redis` starts to throw `RedisTimeoutException` and after some minutes, my asp.net core application crashes.
The Windows event viewer says `The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException`.
Ok, I understand that there is some issue between my app and Redis, but while I can't solve this, how can I prevent the application to shutdown?

Inside `startup.cs`, I tried to put:

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs eventArgs) =>
{
    eventArgs.SetObserved();
    eventArgs.Exception.Handle(ex => true);
};
```

no success....

Any help ?

Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you creating the [`ConnectionMultiplexer`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs) instances?

Maybe you are not reusing a multiplexer instance and creating a lot of connections.

The `ConnectionMultiplexer` object should be shared and reused between callers. It is not recommended to create a `ConnectionMultiplexer` per operation. Check StackExchange.Redis documentation [here](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics#basic-usage) for more information.

About the exception handling on Asp.NET Core, you can use the [`UseExceptionHandler`](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/aspnet-core-diagnostics-middleware-error-handling/#UseExceptionHandler) diagnostic middleware to handle exceptions globally. Check [this article](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/global-exception-handling-in-aspnet-core-webapi/) for a complete explanation

Comment: Hey! We fixed that, now we're using pool strategy and everything is fine but the main question is: How to avoid the application crash?

Comment: Catching the exceptions. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446394/handling-of-transient-network-errors-with-stackexchange-redis) and [this](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/269). And @Ahmet answer

Comment: Is there a way to globally catch redis exceptions in aspnet core?

Comment: @Alexandre I have added a way to catch all redis timeout exceptions globally to my answer.

Comment: @Alexandre you can use a global exception handler. Check [this](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/global-exception-handling-in-aspnet-core-webapi/)

Comment: Tks! Since the question isn't about stackexchange redis, you should edit your answer pointing to Global Exception. Then, I'll mark as answered :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to put the block that throws the exception in a try/catch block? And perhaps make it try a few times with Polly when there is a timeout. https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Normally it shouldn't terminate your app, but since you didn't share any code, We can not be sure.

If you create a service class like below, you can encapsulate all of your redis calls, therefore catch the exceptions.

```
public class EmptyClass
{
    private readonly ConnectionMultiplexer _connectionMultiplexer;

    public EmptyClass(ConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer)
    {
        _connectionMultiplexer = connectionMultiplexer;
    }

    public void Execute(Action<ConnectionMultiplexer> action)
    {
        try
        {
            action.Invoke(_connectionMultiplexer);
        }
        catch(RedisTimeoutException ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public void TestRun()
    {
        Execute((ConnectionMultiplexer obj) =>
        {
            //do stuff with obj.
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @thepirat000's answer, reason is ConnectionMultiplexer

You can use **ConnectionMultiplexer** according your Redis package (StackExchange.Redis or ServiceStack.Redis) and according your deployment environment

In my aspnet core application (like you) i have used StackExchange.Redis and i have deployed to windows server without any error within below Startup.cs settings

```
        #region Redis settings ConnectionMultiplexer
        services.AddDataProtection().ProtectKeysWithDpapi(protectToLocalMachine: true);
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp-keys"))
            .ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG($"CERTIFICATE=HashId:{thumbPrint}", flags: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiNGProtectionDescriptorFlags.None);
        services.AddDataProtection().ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG();

        services.Configure<StorageConfiguration>(new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).Build());
        var redisConf = Configuration.GetSection("RedisConnection").Get<RedisConnection>();
        ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConf.Host.ToString() + ":" + redisConf.Port.ToString());
        services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys");
        services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConf.Host.ToString() + ":" + redisConf.Port.ToString()));
        #endregion
```

Look here for basic usage https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics.html